# How to get the output (stdout/stderr) of a click application?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, debugging

I have a click application installed on Ubuntu Touch, and I need to be able to read its standard output in order to debug it.
Is the output captured somewhere, or is it possible to see it on the terminal when launching the application with the "start" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click apps log all output in ~/.cache/upstart/application-click-$APP_ID.log